# Compilation error while implementing the Depth first search Recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I am new to using recursion for my methods. I tend to steer away from them for quite a few reasons. However, for a project, it seems to easier to have a  recursive method instead of a looping one since I am trying to do Depth First Traversal for a Graph.

Since I am not too well versed in recursion, I don't understand why I am getting the following error.

> This method must return a result of type LinkedList.Node

The code I have currently is:

```
public Node DFSTime(Node node){
    if(node == null){
        System.out.println("No path found");
        return null;
    }
    else if(node.element.equals(destinationAirport)){
        return node;
    }
    else{
        stack.push(node);
        DFSTime(node.nextNode);            
    }
}
```

It is unfinished code since I still need to implement some logic, however, I don't understand how to eliminate the error. Is there something very basic that I am missing?

Comment: There is a path through your method in which it wont return anything. Namely in the `else`-case. Understand what it means to hit the `else` case and then ask yourself which `Node` you want to return in that case. Then return it and Java will be happy.

Comment: Note that you should not use `null` as a sentinel value to indicate absence of a result. Instead, you should use the `Optional` class. Leading to an empty optional if not found and an optional filled with a node if found.

Comment: Right now your else case just tries to find the destination on the next node, but you do not do anything with the result of that search. You just throw away its findings. Rethink what you want to return in your else-case. Hint: Its probably what the other search you are triggering here returns...

Comment: I was thinking of using a stack to track the path I was taking through the graph. And since it is an attribute of the class I implemented the DFS in. So is it unnecessary for me to use recursion since I would be doing nothing with the results of the recursive method?

Comment: You are not understanding. Your code does not do what you intended. It is like you send your friend to the supermarket to buy eggs but when they return, you just throw the eggs directly into the trash and then complain why nobody brought you eggs. Right now, you are triggering the recursion but when it returns with a result, you throw away the result. Instead of returning it out of your method as well, as the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the compilation error is pretty trivial. The compiler clearly tells that didn't provide the result to return for all possible cases.

The more important is that your current approach is ***not correct***.

> it seems to easier to have a recursive method instead of a looping one since I am trying to do Depth First Traversal for a Graph

There are crucial things to consider:

- Field `nextNode` is very suspicious. If each `Node` holds a reference pointing to a single node only, in fact the data structure you've created by definition isn't a *Graph*, but a *Singly linked list*. And doesn't make sense to implement DFS for a list. Every node should point to a ***collection of nodes***, no to a single node.
- You have to distinguish somehow between *unvisited nodes* and nodes that are *already visited*. Or else you might and up with infinite recursion. For that, you can define a `boolean` field `isVisited` inside the `Node`, or place every visited node into a `HashSet`.
- Since you've chosen to create a recursive implementation of DFS, you ***don't*** need to create a *stack*. It's required only for iterative implementation.
- Don't overuse global variables. I guess you might want to be able to check whether it is possible to reach different airports of destination without reinstantiating the graph.
- Use getters and setters instead of accessing fields directly. It's a preferred practice in Java.

Your method might look like this (it's not necessary that `element` should be of type `String` it's just an illustration of the overall idea):

```
public Node DFSTime(Node node, String destinationAirport){
    if(node == null || node.isVisited()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (node.getElement().equals(destinationAirport)) {
        System.out.println("The destination airport was found");
        return node;
    }
    
    node.setVisited(true);
    for (Node neighbour: node.getNeighbours()) {
        Node result = DFSTime(neighbour, destinationAirport);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the node might look like this:

```
public class Node {
    private String element;
    private List<Node> neighbours;
    private boolean isVisited;
    
    public Node(String element, List<Node> neighbours) {
        this.element = element;
        this.neighbours = neighbours;
    }
    
    public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
        isVisited = visited;
    }
    
    public boolean isVisited() {
        return isVisited;
    }
    
    public void addNeighbours(Node neighbour) {
        neighbours.add(neighbour);
    }
    
    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }
    
    public List<Node> getNeighbours() {
        return neighbours;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a default return statement at the end of the function after the closing of the else.

Comment: Just a normal return null should work, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on the logic you want to create.

Comment: @Zabuzard Wdym?

Comment: Read my other comments for details.

Comment: Yes , and you may probably want to do something with "DFSTime(node.nextNode)", eg. return DFSTime(node.nextNode);

Answer (score 1):

In methods conditional blocks (if-else), you need to make sure you are returning appropriate Type from all conditional statements, so that there is no compile-time error. In your case, else block is recursively calling `DFSTime(..)` without returning anything.

You might want to return reference which gets called via recursive call, something like below:

```
public Node DFSTime(Node node){
        if(node == null){
            System.out.println("No path found");
            return null;
        }
        else if(node.element.equals(destinationAirport)){
            return node;
        }
        else{
            stack.push(node);
            Node node = DFSTime(node.nextNode);
            return node;

        }
    }
```